# Add 1st and Last digit of a number

Tags: java

I am trying to add the 1st and last digit of a no but after the programs gets to while loop it starts asking for more inputs,like an infinite loop .

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();//no of testcases
        int n[]=new int[t];
        int last=0,first = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            n[i]=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            last=n[i]%10;
            while(n[i]>=10){
                first=n[i]/10;
            }
            System.out.println(first+last);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    String temp = t+"";
    String[] arr = temp.split("");

    int x = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) + Integer.parseInt(arr[arr.length - 1]);

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In while loop you need to update the value of `n[i]` by using `n[i]=n[i]/10;` which is causing while loop to become infinite loop

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int t = sc.nextInt();//no of testcases
  int n[]=new int[t];
  int last=0,first = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
      n[i]=sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      last=n[i]%10;
      while(n[i]>=10){
          n[i]=n[i]/10;
      }
      first=n[i]/10;
      System.out.println(first+last);
  }
```

Comment: Don't think you'd need to overwrite `first` in every iteration of the `while` loop, rather just take the value once the `while` loop is done

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not updating the value of n[i] with every iteration.

This is my proposed solution for your while loop:

```
    while(n[i]>=10){
        n[i]=n[i]/10;
    }
    first = n[i]
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you could accept the answer. Thanks!